# Como puedo usar for of en un condicional ternario?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy tratando de realizar un filtro de valores de un array de objetos.

Existe un array previo del cual si su id es 18 o 34, debe evaluar en otro array que solo en los objetos con id 21, 22 y 24 debe retornar el pagoId, caso contrario, debe retornar indefinido (algo que en teoria no deberia ocurrir).

Ese array a evaluar el siguiente:

Los objetos que tienen un id y un id de pago.

```
var array= {
    "list_medio_pago":[
    {id:21, pagoId: 40},
    {id:24, pagoId: 40},
    {id: 38, pagoId: 0}
    ]
}
```

Este pagoId siempre sera el mismo, no variara, asi que indistintamente sea se rescate el primer objeto o el segundo etc, deberia traer 40.

Entonces tengo la siguiente funcion ternaria pero no me funciona precisamente por el for, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Asumamos que el array previo ya definio que el id es 18.

```
var pagoId= (id === 18 || id == 34) ? 
for (let value of array.list_medio_pago)
{ (value.id === 21||value.id ===22||value.id ===24) ?
return pagoId = value.pagoId :return pagoId = undefined} : undefined
```

Lo ideal de esto seria que al evaluar la list_medios_pago, omita los id que no corresponden en vez de retornar indefinido.

Como puedo lograr eso?, que errores estoy haciendo?

Saludos!

Comment: Me parece un codigo demasiado largo para un operador ternario, creo que te convendria mas un IF ELSE tradicional
Ademas hay objetos dentro del array, no seria correcto un FOR IN?

Comment: El uso que le das es bastante raro y hace el código difícil de leer.

Comment: cuando dices "al evaluar la list_medios_pago, omita los id que no corresponden", lo que quieres es que te devuelva solo los que el el id sea 21 y 24 y omita el 38 (para tu ejemplo)? Es decir... quieres que la respuesta te devuelva un array con ese 2 elementos?